# RegEx to mach specific value at begining of string

Tags: regex, string, match

Hi I need a RegEx to find if a string starts with "(#)" where # can be any number from 1 to 99999 etc. and anything can follow after "(#)" including symbols

Strings Ex.

```
"(1) S0m3 - Str!n9" - Must found positive
"(67) my $tr!n9 goes H3R3" - Must found positive
"@n0Th3R (7) $tr!nG" - Must found negative
"L0Ok @t the 3nD (57)" - Must found negative
```

I've searched on google but I'm unable to find any results or maybe I don't know what to search for so please guide me to find the answer to this question

Thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
/^\(\d{1,5}\)/
```

that respect the position and the max

Comment: Thank you for your help I've figured out with `^(\()([0-9]{1,4})(\))` but your method also works so thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `^` operator, which designates the beginning of the string.  The pattern `/^\(\d+\)/` will match any number of digits (surrounded by parens) at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Thank you for your help I was able to do it with `^(\()([0-9]{1,4})(\))`